# Dynamic file name loading in Flask static subdirectory

Tags: html, web, flask, static

I want to access a variable image file at my webpage. My html is as follows:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='/<project_name>/image.jpg')}}">
```

Through my flask app, I pass this:

```
return render_template("foo.html", project_name="fooproject")
```

Nesting {{}} within {{}} doesn't work. image.jpg file lies in the fooproject directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jinja2` uses `{{ .. }}` to evaluate any valid expression, so the trick is to use string concatenation like so

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/' + project_name  + '/image.jpg') }}">
```

refer to this [doc](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#expressions)

Comment: Thanks. That did it! :D